# When did enscribing messages on bombs first happen?

Tags: warfare, weapons

I would like to know when and why, messages written on bombs appeared for the first time. In particular if only US crew members used it during the operations in war.

Comment: You should provide references for messages painted on bombs, especially the oldest you can found.

Comment: People do things for a variety of reasons; are you asking for the first known example of a message being written on a bomb, or a weapon?

Comment: @Carlo, would you like to make this question more Aviation specific? Or would you like it to be moved to History.SE?

Comment: Im looking for some more informations about  first apparence of this  type of writings on airplane bombs.... thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question, do not post this information in the comments.

Comment: Carlo, please, either you edit your question to be specifically about aviation and be on topic, or I'll move it to history.SE, where they said they would welcome it.

Comment: Since you have not edited your question, I am moving it to History.SE, where the mods said this could be well received, and the answer as well.

Comment: I can't source, but I'm pretty sure we have messages written on ancient catapult shots. That makes me wonder if the first "bomb" of this sort was a clay jar full of greek fire. Not what you're looking for of course.

Answer (score 7):

This was done since ancient times, and the practice simply carried on.

The Romans used to put witty little insults onto sling-stones, to add some extra bite when used against the enemy.

[Source](http://mentalfloss.com/article/63739/sarcastic-jokes-found-roman-bullets)
[image]

Some of these jokes were innocuous

> Be lodged well
> For Pompey’s Backside

And some were more explicit.

I saw a TV programme where the presenter translated a few choice insults.

But basically, this sending of messages to the enemy has always happened.  Soldiers get bored of sharpening swords, so let their imagination run riot in the interests of boosting morale by making up ruder jokes than your compatriots.

In terms of messages on plane-borne munitions, then it's going to be shortly after plane-borne munitions were first deployed....

Comment: I'd really love to know what TV show that was.

Comment: [This one](http://www.bbc.co.uk/mediacentre/proginfo/2016/17/mary-beards-ultimate-rome) or one similar to it.  It was definitely Mary Beard though.

Comment: And her [book, SQPR](https://www.ft.com/content/4a92b1d4-78c4-11e5-a95a-27d368e1ddf7) - *"Many readers will find pictures of objects such as a rusting Roman gynaecological speculum, a graffito showing Spartacus in the arena, and lead sling bullets inscribed with messages such as “I’m going for Madam Octavius’ arsehole” (from Octavian’s siege of Perusia in 41-40 BC) fascinating on their own account"*